# How can I batch scan?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photos, scanning

In Photoshop CS5, there is built in functionality to get a scan from a scanner. However, the default settings it chooses are unacceptable for my scanner, and it does not remember the setting I use when I need to scan multiple pictures. It simply scans one picture and I'm forced to go through the whole process over again.

Is there any tool and/or Photoshop plugin that will use the same settings for the scanning process over and over? Going through the same UI hundreds of times is getting a bit annoying :)

Answer (score 1):

[AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) is perfect for this kind of automation, if you're running Windows.